# Redirect customer to a specific category page after successful registration

Tags: customer, redirect

I am trying to redirect customer to a specific category based on the entered code.
Everything works fine except the redirect. Magento redirects to homepage instead of category page.
How can I redirect to category page? Any can help?

Customer Registration Form extra field to get the correct category:

```
<input type="text" name="login[passcode]" id="passcode" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Passcode') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
```

My config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Team_Savepasscode>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Team_Savepasscode>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <team_savepasscode>
                <class>Team_Savepasscode_Model</class>
            </team_savepasscode>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <team_savepasscode>
                        <class>team_savepasscode/observer</class>
                        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </team_savepasscode>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Customer registration success event observer:

```
public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $classcode = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('login');
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->setPasscode($classcode);

    $categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
    $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('passcode', $classcode);
    $categories->addUrlRewriteToResult();
    $categories->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(1);
    $categories->load();

    if ($categories->getFirstItem()) {
        $category = $categories->getFirstItem();
        $successUrl = $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true);
        $successUrl = Mage::getUrl($category->getURL($category), array('_secure' => true));
        return $successUrl;
    }
    else {
        echo 'No category exists with the name ' . $name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to redirect to a category,so u can use  *magento FrontController redirction action* from any view.

```
 Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($category->getUrl($category));
 Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
exit();
```

**Place this code on place of**

*`$successUrl = Mage::getUrl($category->getURL($category), array('_secure' => true));`*

Comment: Hi, where should I put your code? @Amit Bera

Comment: check the uoate

Comment: I have replaced it but redirecting to homepage @Amit Bera

Comment: one problem, if I remove `exit();` it redirects to homepage, customer logins, however with the `exit();` it redirects to the category page which is perfect BUT the customer doesn't login which is big problem. how can I redirect to the category page and the customer logins? @Amit Bera

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in your observer file:

```
public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    {
        $classcode = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $session->setPasscode($classcode);

        $categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
        $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $categories->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $categories->addAttributeToFilter('passcode', $classcode);
        $categories->addUrlRewriteToResult();
        $categories->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(1);
        $categories->load();

        if ($category = $categories->getFirstItem()) {
           $successUrl = Mage::getUrl($this->getCategoryUrl($category), array('_secure' => true));
            return successUrl;
        }
        else {
            echo 'No category exists with the name ' . $name;
        }
    }

    public function getCategoryUrl($category)
    {
        if ($category instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category) {
            $url = $category->getUrl();
        } else {
            $url = $this->_getCategoryInstance()
                ->setData($category->getData())
                ->getUrl();
        }

        return $url;
    }
```

Comment: Hi I tried your code and get the following error `Call to a member function getResponse() on a non-object in` @Abdul

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: Not working ir redirects to /customer/account/createpost/ with a complete blank page @Abdul

Answer (score 0):

you have to setRedirect from observer.

```
public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $classcode = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('login');
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    $session->setPasscode($classcode);

    $categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');
    $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
    $categories->addAttributeToFilter('passcode', $classcode);
    $categories->addUrlRewriteToResult();
    $categories->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(1);
    $categories->load();
    foreach($categories $as $category){
       $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
    }


    if ($categories->getFirstItem()) {
        $category = $categories->getFirstItem();
        $successUrl = $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true);
        $successUrl = Mage::getUrl($category->getURL($category), array('_secure' => true));

    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($successUrl);
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    exit;
    }
    else {
        echo 'No category exists with the name ' . $name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not working, still redirects to the homepage @Qaisar Satti

Comment: updated kindly check..

Comment: Redirecting to homepage instead of category page @Qaisar Satti

Comment: remove `$successUrl = $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true);` this and check

Comment: still no change, redirecting to homepage @Qaisar Satti

Comment: my mistake for load category check it now

Comment: unfortunately still no change, redirecting to homepage, do you think my config.xml is correct? maybe something wrong with the it? @Qaisar Satti