# Get category url from custom category attribute

Tags: category, attributes, custom, session, redirect-url

I have tried to redirect customer to a certain category after successful registration however I couldn't achieve it (even with the help in here, still didn't work [stackexchange question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92956/redirect-customer-to-a-specific-category-page-after-successful-registration/92959))so I changed the plan to sort it out with redirecting the customer using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and session variable where I put these in the header.phtml but this time I can't get the category URL for the custom category attribute. Anyone can help?

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
if($session) {
    $customerclass = $session->getPasscode();
    if( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://www.localhost.com/customer/account/create/' && $customerclass != ''){

        $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('passcode', $customerclass)
                  ->addIsActiveFilter()
                  ->addUrlRewriteToResult();

        if($categories->count()){
             $url = $categories->getFirstItem()->getUrl();
             Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
             exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach($categories as $category){
           $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
        }


What is this all about?

Comment: have your created custom category attribute? If created then what is attribute?

Comment: I have corrected the and now I am getting the correct category url but it isn't redirecting to that url. @YiorgosMoschovitis

Comment: I have created the custom category attribute which is passcode and the value is coming from `$customerclass = $session->getPasscode();` @Abdul

Comment: Do you get any category selection from customer while registering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. I assume (by your code) that you want the first category if there are many.

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
          ->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
          ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', 'value')
          ->addIsActiveFilter()
          ->addUrlRewriteToResult();

if($categories->count()){
     $url = $categories->getFirstItem()->getUrl();
     Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
     exit;
}
```

I have to warn you that it's never a good idea to put redirects in template files.

-- Edit --

Try this

```
if($session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')){
     $customerclass = $session->getPasscode();
     $referer = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');

     if( $referer == 'http://www.localhost.com/customer/account/create/' && $customerclass != ''){

         $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('passcode', $customerclass)
              ->addIsActiveFilter()
              ->addUrlRewriteToResult();

         if($categories->count()){
              $url = $categories->getFirstItem()->getUrl();
              if ($url != $referer) { //overkill yeah
                   Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
                   exit;
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: It worked however the browser first gives Error too many redirect loop and then it redirects to the category page. Is that normal? @YiorgosMoschovitis

Comment: Well... I told you about redirects in phtml files. Never a good idea. Did you include your refferer check with my code? It seems like you haven't

Comment: Also thank you for your warning but I couldn't get it working in any other way. I have tried using event hook but it didn't work. You can see it here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92956/redirect-customer-to-a-specific-category-page-after-successful-registration/92959 Do you suggest a different way? if yes how? @YiorgosMoschoviti

Comment: I have updated the code you can have a look at it @YiorgosMoschovitis